# Access Query equation

Tags: ms-access, math

I'm attempting to do a simple equation and I keep getting "Data mismatch in Criteria" error and for the life of me I can't figure out why. I'm attempting to subtract the number 45000 from the number of entries in a particular column. What I have is this:
    Exp1: 45000-[Customer Last Name]

The idea is to see how many more records we need to do. This should be simple but for some reason it's been causing me an issue for the last day or so. I've been looking around with Google search but haven't had much luck. Everything I've tried that was suggested hasn't worked. I don't know why something so simple should be so difficult. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
-D

Answer (score 0):

Okay after tinkering some more I finally found the answer... I had to go this route to make it work:
    `Round(45000) - Count([Customer Last Name)]`

This worked and got me where I needed to go.
Now I have to figure out how to setup averages based on date.... joy.

-D